# Sort the array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function below:

```
  function GeraHorario(inicio,fim,tempoConsulta)
  {
    var agenda = []
    var data = new Date(2016, 0, 1, inicio, 0, 0, 0)
    var horainicial = inicio
    while (data.getDate() == 1) {
      if(data.getHours() < fim)
      {
          var horario = data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
          data.setMinutes(data.getMinutes()+tempoConsulta);
          var d1 = horario.replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
          agenda.push(d1);
      }else{break}
    }
    console.log(agenda)
    return agenda
  }
```

This function generates this array

```
["09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50"]
```

**I make a map in the array and it looks like this.**
 **This is the function used in map**

```
 function GroupHoras(array)
  {
    var result = array.reduce(function( map, hourStr ) {
        var hour = hourStr.charAt(0) + hourStr.charAt(1);
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(hour)) map[hour] = [];
        map[hour].push(hourStr);
        return map;
    }, {});

    return result
  }
```

It looks like after the map

```
Object {10: Array[6], 11: Array[6], 12: Array[6], 13: Array[6], 14: Array[6], 15: Array[6], 16: Array[6], 17: Array[6], 18: Array[6], 09: Array[6]}
```

However as you can see, the value 09 should be at the beginning, go to the end of the array of objects. How do I ordernar this subject increasingly?

Comment: Have you try .sort() on your object ?

Comment: An object (map/associative array - whatever you want to call it) has no order as such.

Comment: You're going to need to either use an Array of Objects (as Arrays are ordered), or keep an Array of ordered keys representing properties on your unordered Object.

Comment: @Rena if you want you can add your arrays into an array so the index of the array will be like in the object and it will be ordered as well.

Comment: Or you can move the "order" issue to the part of code that uses your object (in the display part, or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "order" the properties of a javascript object.

Perhaps a good workaround is to store an an array containing the property names in the order you want to display them, and use that for the purpose of ordering:

```js
 var order = ["09","10","11"]
 var obj = {"10":"ten","11":"Eleven", "09": "Nine"};
 for(var i=0;i<order.length;i++){
    var prop = order[i];
   console.log(prop,obj[prop]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object arrays are not sortable objects. Every browser will show them in different orders even with the same set of data.

What you can do is to create a two dimensional JS array and the first index elements will be the hours and the second index will be a one-dimensional array which, I suppose, you keep the items in that hour.

So additionally to your second function you should be able to use the following codes to create your own sorting function and get a two-dimensional array instead of using a JS object array.

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var hour in map){
    var arr2 = new Array();
    arr2.push(hour, map[hour]);

    arr.push(arr2);
}

arr.sort();//After this you will have a sorted array
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not guarantee key order in maps. See this answer for quotes from the spec: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

However there are ways to get around this, the **second** answer to this question shows how you can use JSON.sringify() to ensure proper ordering: [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)